# 'npm start' in node.js doesn't works

Tags: node.js

node App.js works, but npm start doesn't works.

I just followed [this nodejs tutorial](http://webframeworks.kr/tutorials/nodejs/api-server-by-nodejs-01/) (tutorial is written by Korean).

I tried to change code to:

"scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server"
 }
but it didn't work.

this is my code:
App.js

```
const http = require('http');

const hostname = '127.0.0.1';
const port = 3000;

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.statusCode = 200;
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
  res.end('Hello World\n');
});

server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
  console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "codlab-nodejs",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

package-lock.json

```
{
  "name": "codlab-nodejs",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "lockfileVersion": 1
}
```

This is the err msg.

```
C:\Users\김동희\codlab-nodejs>npm start

> codlab-nodejs@1.0.0 start C:\Users\김동희\codlab-nodejs
> node js

internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:638
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\김동희\codlab-nodejs\js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:829:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! codlab-nodejs@1.0.0 start: `node js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the codlab-nodejs@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\김동희\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-08-03T14_03_42_211Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your package.json change the value of the property "start".

Replace:

```
"start": "node js"
```

With:

```
"start": "node App.js"
```

Answer (score 2):

The `start` npm script is trying to run a file called `js`, which does not exist and consequently fails.

Instead, set your `start` npm script to be the correct command that asks Node.js to run your `App.js` file.

Your `package.json` would include something like this:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node App.js"
  }
```